# Check if the Array has something like my Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a array of strings . I need to check in the array if it has something like "abcd". How to achive this in C#. I tried using the

```
var pathBits = new[] {"abcde ","abcd &"};
var item ="abcd";
var results = Array.FindAll(pathBits, s => s.Equals(item ));
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help? Also, next time you ask a question please provide sample input AND output data. That would make it much easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say **'something like "abcd"'** do you mean *"Starts with"* or *"Contains"*?

The current code will only find strings in pathBits which are exactly equal to item ("abcd" ?)

The general shape is fine but to find non-exact matches you need to change the predicate

e.g.

```
string[] src = new[] { "abcde", "abcd &" };
var results = Array.FindAll<string>(src, name => name.Contains("abcd"));
```

This can also be implemented using the Linq IEnumerable<> extensions

e.g.

```
string[] src = new[] { "abcde", "abcd &" };
var results = src.Where(name => name.Contains("abcd"));
```

hth,
Alan.

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this:

```
var result = pathBits.Any(y => y.Contains(item));
```

That will give you true if the array contains an item that has a value like `item`. If you want to select all those values you should use:

```
var result = pathBits.Where(y => y.Contains(item));
```

which will give you an `IEnumerable` of the items from the list that contain the value `item`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some use

```
string[] pathBits = { "abcde ", "abcd &" };
        var item = "abcd";

        if (pathBits.Contains(item)) ;
        {
        }
```

You cannot use

```
var pathbits = { "abcde ", "abcd &" };
```

Please let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
string[] pathBits = { "abcde ", "abcd &", "222" };
        var item = "abcd";
        var results = Array.FindAll<string>(pathBits, s => s.Contains(item));
```

results will have 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but this would get all array allements that contain the string "abcd" -

```
String[] pathBits = {"abcde ","abcd &"};
var item ="abcd";
var results = pathBits.Where(s => s.IndexOf("abcd") > -1);
```